# Let $p>1$ be a natural number. Prove that $n=\sqrt[p-1]{p}$ can't be a natural number if $p>2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

Let $p>1$ be a natural number. Prove that $n=\sqrt[p-1]{p}$ can't be a natural number if $p>2$. $n=2$ for $p=2$ of course !

Equivalently show that $p=n^{p-1}$ admits for $p>1$ $(n,p)=(2,2)$ as the only pair of non zero natural numbers as solution.

The question is related to exercise n°5 of Bourbaki's first treatise on Algebra [chapter I-III]. At this stage the reader is supposed to have read the treatise covering Set theory. He/She isn't supposed to know what a square root nor even know what a real number is :-)

Thanks

Comment: it looks like Fermat theorem if (a,p)=1 or not, but too "difficult" for the beginning I think x)

Comment: Not calculus, though.... fixed the tags.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Calculus can be used, though not in an essential way.

Comment: @Pythagoras: If this is done before they know what a real number is, then how would you justify the use of calculus? In any case, what you may or may not use in the solution should not be the sole tag for the problem.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Good point! I haven't read that they did not even introduce square root yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim:** For all $n\geq 3$, $2^{n-1}\gt n$.

This holds for $n=3$: $2^{3-1} = 4\gt 3=n$.

Assume that $2^{n-1}\gt n$, $n\geq 3$. Then $2^{n}\gt 2n$, and $2n = n+n\gt n+1$. Therefore, $2^{(n+1)-1} \gt n+1$.

This establishes the claim by induction.

Now, this means that for all $p\gt 2$, $n\geq 2$, $n^{p-1}\geq 2^{p-1}\gt p\gt 1^{p-1}$. Thus, $p$ cannot be a $(p-1)$st power of a natural number.

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks a lot Arturo. Pete

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction, suppose $2<p\in \Bbb N$ and $n^{p-1}=p$ with $n\in \Bbb N.$ Then $n>1,$  so let $n=1+x$ with $x>0.$ Since $2\le p-1\in \Bbb N,$  by the Binomial Theorem we have $$p=n^{p-1}=(1+x)^{p-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\binom {p-1}{j}x^j\ge$$ $$\ge 1+\binom {p-1}{1}x+\binom {p-1}{2}x^2>$$ $$>1+\binom {p-1}{1}x=1+(p-1)x$$...because $x>0$ so each  term in the Binomial Expansion of $(1+x)^{p-1}$ is positive.

Therefore $p>1+(p-1)x,$ that is, $p-1>(p-1)x,$ and since $p-1>0,$ this implies $1>x.$ But $x>0,$ so $n=1+x$ is  a natural number with $1<n<2,$ which is absurd.

Remark: We can, instead, employ induction on $p\ge 3$ to show that if $x>0$ and $3\le  p\in \Bbb N$ then $(1+x)^{p-1}>1+(p-1)x.$

Comment: Daniel your proof involving binomial expansion is perfect too. I consider the induction based proof given by Arturo Magidin above a bit more concise, noticing that you also indicated the way to such a proof based on induction. Thanks a lot.